# What determines the height of a tetrahedron?

Tags: geometry

> Tetrahedron $ABCD$ has $AB=AC=AD=BD=17$, $BC=8$, and $CD=15$. Find the volume of $ABCD$.

What are the requirements to determine the height of a $3$D figure if we want to show we have a dihedral angle of $90^{\circ}$. More specifically, say we are given two planes that intersect at a dihedral angle. Is it enough to say that in a tetrahedron as shown below that since the altitude of $ABD$, $AT$, is perpendicular to $DB$ and the median of triangle, $CT$, is perpendicular to $AT$, that $AT$ must in fact be the altitude of the tetrahedron? I am wondering if there is a theorem about this in general. Also, take note that $\triangle{CAT}$ is a right triangle.

If my reasoning above is correct then the answer on the board follows.

[image]

Comment: That looks correct.

Comment: The volume $V = 170\sqrt{3}$ is correct. 
It is the number one get using [Cayley Menger determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html).

$$288V^2 =
\left|\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & AB^2 & AC^2 & AD^2\\
1 & AB^2 & 0 & BC^2 & BD^2\\
1 & AC^2 & BC^2 & 0 & CD^2\\
1 & AD^2 & BD^2 & CD^2 & 0
\end{matrix}\right|
$$

Comment: 1. You argument is valid though you should justify why $CT \perp AT$ (congruence between $\triangle ADT$ and $\triangle ACT$). 
2. In general, if a line $\ell$ intersect a plane $H$ at a point $p$ and 
perpendicular to two lines on $H$ passing through $p$, then $\ell$ is perpendicular to all lines on $H$ through $p$.
3. (+1) for the approach, that's smart.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand here is that you are making the following argument:

Let $AT$ be an altitude of $ABD$. Since $ABD$ is isosceles, $AT$ is also a median of $ABD$, so $T$ is the midpoint of $BD$. $BCD$ is a right triangle by Pythagoras, hence its median $CT$ has length $\frac{1}{2} BD$. Then you calculate $AT$ and use Pythagoras to prove that $CAT$ has a right angle at $T$. Now you would like to conclude that $AT$ is perpendicular to plane $BCD$.

Yes, you can say this because $AT$ is perpendicular to two intersecting lines in plane $BCD$, namely $CT$ and $BD$. Therefore $AT$ is perpendicular to the whole plane. I'm not sure what the name of this theorem is in English. In Russian it's called the [theorem on the three perpendiculars.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85) (The Wikipedia article doesn't link to any other language versions.) In your particular situation, the lines both meet $AT$, but in general this isn't required - both lines could even be skew to $AT$. The important thing is that they're both in plane $BCD$ and not parallel.

However, let me suggest a different approach. If you call $H$ the projection of $A$ onto plane $BCD$, then $AB^2 = AH^2 + HB^2$,  $AC^2 = AH^2 + HC^2$,  $AD^2 = AH^2 + HD^2$ by Pythagoras. Since $A$ is equidistant from $B$, $C$ and $D$, this shows that $H$ too must be equidistant from $B$, $C$ and $D$. Therefore $H$ must be the centre of the circumscribed circle to $BCD$. In the case of a right triangle, this is the midpoint of the hypotenuse.

I didn't understand what you were saying about a dihedral angle of $90^{\circ}$, or how that's relevant to this problem. A dihedral angle is between two planes (or two half-planes).